# Noflo example : Running inside browser

Tags: browser, noflo

We are trying to get a simple noflo example running inside a browser as described the `noflojs.org/documentation/fbp/` [Language for Flow-Based Programming]

We tried to refer to some examples available on GitHub

1. `github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app`
2. `github.com/noflo/noflo-websocket`
3. `github.com/bergie/flowcopter`

We tried npm install; grunt build. We get the below error and are not able to proceed beyond this:

> Running "noflo_browser:build" (noflo_browser) task     install
>   noflo/noflo@master      Warning: dns lookup failed Use --force to
>   continue.

Any idea what are we missing ?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the question the build setup for the projects mentioned was still based on [Component.js](https://github.com/componentjs/component) which had become unmaintained.

Nowadays we're using NPM for installing dependencies and [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/) for browser builds.

Suggested fix would be to fetch the latest versions of these repos, do `npm install` and build again. This will bring the build up to spec.

If you're using the old build setup in your own projects, [this PR](https://github.com/bergie/flowcopter/pull/1/files) is a handy example on what to change to go from Component.js to WebPack.